# Leaflet-Routing-Machine Route goes back to previous position and comes back to at the end of every change

Tags: reactjs, leaflet-routing-machine

I'm using Leaflet-Routing-Machine on ReactJS project. I've routes on the map. Problem occurs when the position of map changes or during zoom in / zoom out.

When I start dragging the map to change position, there is no issue, but when I stop the dragging, the route go back to its previous position first when I start dragging and then comes back to it's final position. So, it is not looking good visually. Is there anyone had faced this problem before?

Here is the video image so you can see visually, what is the problem.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dcVsKK2PA1g&feature=youtu.be

Comment: It is rather hard to visualise what you mean. Can you supply a Fiddle or a Snippet to explain what the problem is?

Comment: @halfer Thank you man. Here you go, I uploaded a video to youtube so you can see what is the problem, visually.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dcVsKK2PA1g&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Could you perhaps show some code as well, or the most relevant part of your code, pasted in the question? I don't use React, but say a React reader were to see your question, how could they replicate the problem you are having?